# How to make ESC key exit the alt+tab menu instead of switching tabs

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab, switching

so I'm on windows 10 (just moved from mac) and if I have say Tab "A" and Tab "B" opened I can press alt+tab then it will highlight tab B which is good, if I release alt+tab or press enter it will switch to the highlighted tab, aka tab B. All good so far

now say I pressed alt-tab but before releasing I decided I wanted to stay on tab A, or I just clicked it to check other opening tabs for say any red lines in terminal or so, so I want to close it, on mac I used to simply press "ESC" and it closes it, but here on windows when I press ESC it acts as if I pressed enter and just opens the current highlighted tab (Tab B) instead of the one I'm on (Tab A), I can't find any shortcut that exits the alt+tab menu without opening the highlighted tab (unless I move my cursor or keep switching tabs till I return back which is very Inefficient)

Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: What you want is not natively available. Have you looked at Auto Hotkey?

Comment: Well, I will give a look at AutoHotKey and post the script here if I managed to do it when I have time, Thanks

Comment: @John actually I was just on my brother's PC and when I pressed ESC when the alt+tab menu was opened it closed... he only had one program that changes how the dock looks like and when I quit it from task manager the behavior didn't change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was powertoys issue, i swapped alt with ctrl and set a hotkey for ctrl + tab to be mapped to alt+tab, but forgot to do same for ctrl+shift+tab and ctrl+esc